# How to align text vertically in table

Tags: tables, formatting, vertical-alignment, cline

I have designed a table that is looking well except for one part, that is not aligned vertically to the center. I think it has to do with the line separating "Property at 27ºC" from the actual properties bellow it, and this `\cline` is covering a bit of the text bellow it.

This is the code:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Process}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Property at 27ºC} \\ \cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}        & S      & $\sigma$    & k       & zT       \\
\midrule
Unannealed                  & 140    & 1052        & 9.73    & 0.0636   \\
Annealed at 1345ºC          & 155    & 768         & 7.67    & 0.0722   \\
Annealed at 1365ºC          & 151    & 845         & 6.00    & 0.0964   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Influence of annealing at 27ºC}
\label{tab:influenceofannealing}
\end{table}
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image: Table I have now]

Is there a way I can set the text of the four columns a bit lower or set as vertically centered to the confined space? Also set the cell "Property at 27ºC" a bit higher?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about `\cmidrule` instead of `\cline`? You will however have to adjust the value of the `multirow` to something like `\multirow{2.35}{*}{Process}`.

Comment: The `cellspace` package resolves spacing issues like yours.

Comment: You don't have to put an empty `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` in the second line of your `\multirow`, an empty cell is an empty cell, doesn't matter how it is aligned. Also, contrarily to what @leandriis suggests, I'd not try to guess the value correctly, but use the correct offset as a correction.

Comment: Incidentally, it's typographically inappropriate to use the `º` symbol to denote temperature in degrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning the comments of [@leandris](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536754/how-to-align-text-vertically-in-table#comment1356076_536754) and myself into an answer.

The following uses `\cmidrule` and adjusts the `\multirow` accordingly. In addition it typesets the temperatures using the `siunitx` package (thanks to [@Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536754/how-to-align-text-vertically-in-table/536756#comment1356090_536754) for pointing to the degree symbol used)

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}[-\dimexpr0.5\cmidrulewidth+\cmidrulesep]{Process}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Property at \SI{27}{\celsius}} \\ \cmidrule{2-5}
                                & S      & $\sigma$    & k       & zT       \\
\midrule
Unannealed                      & 140    & 1052        & 9.73    & 0.0636   \\
Annealed at \SI{1345}{\celsius} & 155    & 768         & 7.67    & 0.0722   \\
Annealed at \SI{1365}{\celsius} & 151    & 845         & 6.00    & 0.0964   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Influence of annealing at \SI{27}{\celsius}}
\label{tab:influenceofannealing}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to employing `\cmidrule` instead of `\cline` -- a suggestion already employed in [@Skillmon's earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/536756/5001) -- I would also like to suggest that you employ the `S` column type (provided by the `siunitx` package) instead of the `c` column type for the four data columns. And, rather than using the typographically inappropriate `º` symbol for degrees (Celsius), do please write `\SI{...}{\celsius}`. Finally, I= would also like to suggest that you simplify the layout by placing the word "Process" into the top-left cell and make the header over the four data columns less wordy (and less-redundant, given that the information is already given in the caption).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman text and math font -- optional
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l T{3.0}T{4.0}T{1.2}T{1.4} @{}}
\toprule
Process & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Property} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
& {S [\si{\micro\volt\per\kelvin}]}    
& {$\sigma$ [\si{\S\per\centi\meter}]} 
& {k [\si{\watt\per\meter\per\kelvin}]} 
& {zT}
\midrule
Unannealed                      & 140 & 1052 & 9.73 & 0.0636   \\
Annealed at \SI{1345}{\celsius} & 155 &  768 & 7.67 & 0.0722   \\
Annealed at \SI{1365}{\celsius} & 151 &  845 & 6.00 & 0.0964   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Influence of annealing at \SI{27}{\celsius} (\SI{300}{\kelvin})}
\label{tab:influenceofannealing}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is yet another alternative using the `cellspace` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newlength\TopBottomLimit
\setlength\TopBottomLimit{0.7em}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{\TopBottomLimit}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\TopBottomLimit}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{O{l}O{c}O{c}O{c}O{c}}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{*}[-\TopBottomLimit]{Process} & \multicolumn{4}{O{c}}{Property at \SI{27}{\celsius}} \\ \cline{2-5}
                                        & \si{\celsius}      & $\sigma$    & k       & zT       \\
        \midrule
        Unannealed                      & 140    & 1052        & 9.73    & 0.0636   \\
        Annealed at \SI{1345}{\celsius} & 155    & 768         & 7.67    & 0.0722   \\
        Annealed at \SI{1365}{\celsius} & 151    & 845         & 6.00    & 0.0964   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Influence of annealing at \SI{27}{\celsius}}
    \label{tab:influenceofannealing}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Remark

You place the information that the process takes places at 27°C both in the header of the table and in the caption. I don't think that this redundancy contributes to a better readability of your document. You may think about reducing the degree of redundancy. In this case the issue will solve itself.